# Hide the gridlines in Excel Chart winforms vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms, charts

My winforms application creates an excel spreadsheet with a column chart. I am trying to hide the gridlines in the Chart. Appreciate the help Thanks

```
    'Create a Chart
    Dim ChartPage As Excel.Chart
    Dim xlCharts As Excel.ChartObjects
    Dim myChart As Excel.ChartObject
    Dim chartRange As Excel.Range

    xlCharts = xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects
    myChart = xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 700, 450)
    ChartPage = myChart.Chart
    chartRange = xlWorkSheet.Range("A10", "K13")
    ChartPage.SetSourceData(Source:=chartRange)
    ChartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnStacked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I regret I am not conversant in VB.net, but I'll bet you can quickly convert this C# interop code that will remove the gridlines:

```
myChart.Chart.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).MajorGridLines.Delete();
```

Comment: Thanks Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

2nd Solution that also works which I found is

```
    ChartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).MajorGridLines.Format.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse
```

Link: [Creating/formatting a chart](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/09/06/creatingformatting-a-chart/)